# Problem with creating Text object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a problem with creating coin counter for a game.
Underneath is a part of my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text coins_text;
    void Start()
    {
        coins_text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
```

the problem seems to be in the Update method:

```
    void Update()
    {
        coins_text.text = coins.ToString();
    }
```

Here is the error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Any help is appreciated.
Jump.Update () (at Assets/Scenes/Jump.cs:34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome new user,

1. don't bother using "GetComponent",
2. instead use

   public Text coins_text;
3. and open your editor and literally drag the "text item" in to that slot

(If you're not familiar with how to do that, check some basic tutes on Unity!)

Next,

4. if you do use "GetComponent"

add this line of code

```
if (coins_text == null) { Debug.Log("there's a f'up"); }
coins_text.text = coins.ToString();
```

it will clearly tell you if the Text item is actually missing!

5. NEVER EVER set the text in Update.  You can't do that.

You should only set it when the integer value of "coins" changes.

There are many ways to do that, but just do it simply.  Have a separate function you call, to change the display, when you need to.